# Proof that if a and b are integers such that ab ≡ 0 (mod n) then either a ≡ 0 (mod n) or b ≡ 0 (mod n) even if n was a power of a prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I am lost trying to proof this statement. If anyone can guide me on how to proceed on solving this, that will be appreciated.

1.) Proof that if a and b are integers such that ab ≡ 0 (mod n) then either a ≡ 0 (mod n) or b ≡ 0 (mod n) even if n was a power of a prime.

My attempt at this would have been to pick random values for a, b, and prime n, then attempt to solve it.

Comment: What about $a=b=2$, $n=4$?

Comment: So then would I apply the values to the mods and see if its true or false otherwise?

Comment: This statement is false,unless n is prime.  You can find this proof pretty much anywhere. It's simply because primes are numbers such that if n divides ab, then n divides a or b.

Comment: @KonoDDa $2$ is not divisible by $4$, so $a$ and $b$ will not be congruent to $0\mod{n}$

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I was looking past that. I over complicated it. Thanks.

Comment: The statement becomes true if $a,b$ are coprime, are you sure that was not part of the question.

Comment: @N.S. Yeah that was all.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun I know how to use them, its just that I feel lazy, unless it comes to complicated expressions. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $a = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ $b=\prod q_i^{j_i}$, $q_i, p_i$ prime be the prime factorizations. And let $n = p^m$

$ab \equiv 0 \mod n$ means $p^n|\prod p_i^{k_i}\prod q_i^{j_i}$

It's simple to make cases where $p = p_s = q_r$ for some $p_s,q_r$ and $k_s + j_r \ge m$ but $k_s,j_r < m$ where this statement wouldn't hold.

Example.  $n= 2^2 = 4$ and $a= b =2$.  So $2*2\equiv 0 \mod 4$ but $2 \not \equiv 0 \mod 4$.

Less trivial $a = 6; b=15; n= 3^2 = 9$. So $6*15 \equiv 0 \mod 9$ but neither $6$ nor $15$ are equiv $0 \mod 9$.